# Loop through paths D3 with .each

Tags: javascript, d3.js

I'm trying to make my first map in D3. The map is showing fine, but I now want to loop through each path I appended to my SVG. This is the code I'm working on:

```
 var path = d3.geo.path()
                  .projection(projection);
 //Create SVG element
 var svg = d3.select("body")
             .append("svg")
             .attr("width", w)
             .attr("height", h);


 //Load in GeoJSON data
 d3.json("/data/friesland.json", function (json) {

     //Bind data and create one path per GeoJSON feature
        svg.selectAll("path")
        .data(json.features)
        .enter()
        .append("path")
        .attr("d", path)
        .attr('fill', 'rgba(29,91,85,1)')
        .attr('stroke', 'white')
        .attr('stroke-width', 1);

 });

 svg.selectAll('path').each(function (d, i) { console.log('test'); });
```

It seems that there are no paths binded to the svg, how can I change this?
Thank you!

Comment: `d3.json` executes *asychronously*. Try putting your last line inside the `function` you're passing to `d3.json`.

Comment: Thanks for your quick reply, this makes a lot of sense!

Comment: I added my comment as an answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`d3.json` executes [*asychronously*](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/hh700330.aspx) (see [docs](https://github.com/mbostock/d3/wiki/Requests)). Try selecting the `<path>`s inside the function you pass to `d3.json`, like so:

```
d3.json("/data/friesland.json", function (json) {

 //Bind data and create one path per GeoJSON feature
 svg.selectAll("path")
    .data(json.features)
    .enter()
    .append("path")
    .attr("d", path)
    .attr('fill', 'rgba(29,91,85,1)')
    .attr('stroke', 'white')
    .attr('stroke-width', 1);


 svg.selectAll('path').each(function (d, i) { console.log('test'); });

});
```

Now you will only select the `<path>`s after the SVG has been populated.

Answer (score 0):

As mdml suggested, you want to put your selectAll inside the callback to your json load - otherwise it will happen before the binding occurs.

```
var path = d3.geo.path()
              .projection(projection);
var svg = d3.select("body")
         .append("svg")
         .attr("width", w)
         .attr("height", h);


d3.json("/data/friesland.json", function (json) {

    svg.selectAll("path")
    .data(json.features)
    .enter()
    .append("path")
    .attr("d", path)
    .attr('fill', 'rgba(29,91,85,1)')
    .attr('stroke', 'white')
    .attr('stroke-width', 1);
   svg.selectAll('path').each(function (d, i) { console.log('test'); });
 });
```